# Is there ACH analogue in Asia?

Tags: ach

Wiki [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Clearing_House):

> Automated Clearing House (ACH) is an electronic network for financial transactions ***in the United States***. ACH processes large volumes of credit and debit transactions in batches.

Is there ACH analogue in Asia?

Answer (score 2):

ACH as offered in US is a very broad and versatile network used for a range of business case. There is no other network as versatile. In Europe UK has BACS as equivalent about 50-70% of what US-ACH offers. Most European countries also have ACH [Collectively Called ACH, have 90% of the layouts that are identical, called by different names domestically, different business capabilities and rules].

Most countries in Asia also have similar networks. For example in India there is ECS now replaced by NACH. In Singapore/Indonesia/Thailand/Malaysia they have Giro's. China has CNAPS and BEPS.

So essentially every country has addressed the business need differently and bis.org has a decent over-view country wise on the clearing systems available.